# Identifying story on male human protagonist helping aliens crashed in the mountains

Tags: story-identification, aliens, first-contact

This is a story I read about 20 years ago, but translated so it may have been older. Can't find it by google/google books.

What I remember: there was a single, human male protagonist, in the mountains. He finds a crashed alien ships with small, child-like aliens who are very weak physically. It turns out they need heat to repair their ship, so he cuts some trees to burn, helping them via physical strength which they don't have. Here I get a bit fuzzy but apparently they couldn't do it for philosophical reasons (their culture doesn't allow harming any living things).

I do remember the main character having an English name, although I don't recall the specific name, so I am about 80% confident the original is in English. :) Sorry if I am leading you on a wild goose chase...

Thanks a lot for any insight!

Lucian

Comment: Was it a short story or a novel? What language did you read it in?

Comment: Short story, I read it in Romanian in what we call an "almanac" (but it doesn't mean exactly the same as in English, it is a collection of writings on various topics.) Thanks for the quick reaction!

Comment: [Here](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_ttype&ORDERBY=title_copyright&USE_3=title_copyright&USE_2=title_language&START=100&TERM_3=199_&TERM_1=SHORTFICTION&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&TERM_2=Romanian&OPERATOR_3=exact&OPERATOR_2=exact&OPERATOR_1=exact&TYPE=Title) is an incomplete list of science fiction and fantasy short fiction titles published in Romanian in the 1990s. Does anything here look like it could be it?

Comment: Can't be 100% because many of them don't have descriptions (I looked up more likely ones) but I don't think so.